# qr code decoding on uC

Tags: microcontroller, qr-code

i am working on a project that uses qr code to check in guest at an event. i intended to implement it as a mobile app on android but my professor require a hardware element to the project. so my question s are

1. can i do decoding of a qr-code image on a microcontroller with a CMOS camera and which one is recommended?
2. if not, is it possible to use a cmos camera with a microcontroller  to take the picture and send it to a pc to do the decoding and which microcontroller is recommended?

any other suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to decode QR Code with something less powerful than ARM.

**Ad 1.**
Of course you can, but, as I said, I wouldn't try on something less powerful than ARM (unless you're a C ninja and you can fit into, say, AVR for this task).
Decoding QR code itself isn't that hard and I you'll be able to write it by yourself (or use existing library).

**Ad 2.**
You'll need some connectivity to do that. There are many Bluetooth, Ethernet and WLAN boards around (in my experience, best choice may be Bluetooth, you may get away without implementing network stack).

[Useful link.](http://forums.arm.com/index.php?/topic/13634-how-to-interface-cmos-camera-module-with-cortex-m3/)

Comment: thanks alot. but i am a bit new to uC's, which ARM  is likely to give best performance at minimum price- ARM7,ARM9 or cortex-M3

Comment: I think the OP was asking whether a CMOS camera would provide a good enough image to decode, rather than whether there was enough processing power.

Comment: @Sean Owen Then, yes. QR codes provide enough correction level. user913997, Maybe Atmel ARMs?

Answer (score 0):

Decoding QR codes is relatively easy as barcodes go. You can use source code from the [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) library, running on the server side (it's primarily Java) to do the decoding. Decoding is "fast"; on the original Android (ARM7) devices it would still decode in about 100ms.

But I think your question is about image quality. I am not familiar with the output of CMOS sensors, but for QR codes, you don't need color data and you don't need much resolution (240x240 works for most QR codes). If anything the issue is focus.